# Fixing rendering seed for python graphviz fdp

Tags: python, graphviz

I create a graph using Graphviz Digraph and everytime I render it, the nodes appear at a different place. Is there a way to fix the "rendering seed" so the **graph will be always the same** ?

NB: **I cannot set manually the node positions** since I have tens of nodes in my use case.

Here is a code example generating everytime a different image:

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph(engine='fdp', format='png')
dot.node("A")
dot.node("B")
dot.node("C")
dot
```

and two examples of outputs:

[image: first output]
[image: second output]

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the [`start`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/start/) attribute is supposed to be used by both the `fdp` and `neato` layout engines. It is a [`startType`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/startType/) attribute that is allowed on Graphs. The following *should* work:

```
digraph {
    graph [start=your_seed]
    ...
}
```

which you would set in python by

```py
dot.attr("graph", {
    "start": "your_seed"
})
```

The graphviz documentation shows [an example of using setting the `start` attribute](https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqNeatoEdgeCrossings), but only for `neato`. I have been unable to find any bug reports regarding this feature failing for `fdp`, so I have to assume that it is an error in the documentation and `fdp` does not support the `start` attribute.

I've included the relevant documentation below (dated June 2021) in the event that this is updated. I've been testing with graphviz version `2.43.0`.

---

[image: Documentation of the start attribute]

---

[image: documentation of the start type]

---